# Is there a maximum number of images for Channel Images?

Tags: channel-images, devdemon

Is there a maximum number of images which can be uploaded using Channel Images? We did not set a maximum number per user, but somehow when more than 30 images are uploaded, the images above the 30 will not show on the page.

The images ARE uploaded and shown in EE. So, if you move image #32 down, it WILL show.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly set a limit parameter higher than 30 (i.e.: limit="500"), as Channel Images defaults to 30 max (similar to how EE Channel entries defaults limit to 100):

From the [docs](http://www.devdemon.com/documentation/tag/images/):

> This parameter limits the number of images on any given page. The
>   limit will default to 30 entries if a value is not specified. If you
>   are using pagination then this will determine the number of entries
>   shown per page.

Comment: Thanks, feel kinda stupid that it said it so clearly in the docs, must have totally overlooked it.